# How to pass Activity object into onBindViewHolder method for using that one in getScaledBitmap method

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView.ViewHolder with next fields:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView birdImageView;
    private Bird bird;
```

my onBindViewHolder method has to use `PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap()` method, that needs Activity object

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(birds.get(position), context);
}

private void setData(){
    this.bird = bird;
                                            // here problem in context parameter        
Bitmap bitmap = PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap(bird.getBirdImageString(), context);
        birdImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Problem: Appears next error:

```
error: incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to Activity
                Bitmap bitmap = PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap(bird.getBirdImageString(), context);
```

Question: How to make my this getScaledBitmap method work? How to pass Activity object in my RecyclerView adapter.
Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this `{(AppCompatActivity)context}` instead of `context`

Answer (score 0):

change your adapter context to activity context and then pass this activity context to getScaledBitmap method

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the Activity context for the method. You do this by using context retrieved by calling the getActivity() method in the fragment where you create the adapter instance.

**Adapter**:

```
private final RecyclerView recyclerView;
private final List<Bird> birds;
private ImageView birdImageView;
private Context context;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super(view);
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {  
    holder.setData(birds.get(position), context);
}

public setData(Bird bird) {
    Bitmap bitmap = PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap(bird.getBirdImageString(), context);
    birdImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

**Fragment**:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView();
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new recyclerAdapter(getActivity(), recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```